# When using Tkinter Notebooks, how can I use a StringVar from one tab for another tab object while allowing for f string usage and live updates

Tags: python, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

I am creating a little project for helping creating BG3 mods. My end goal is to have multiple tabs where I can enter the data, and it exports the files when I save.

I am able to perform the saving and tab creation with no issue. What I would like to happen is in the ConfigTab I type in a name for the custom class the mod will create (this is for DND if it helps). Then in the LocalizationTab I would like for there to be a label with an entry field. The label would read the class name from the ConfigTab and show as Class Name Description:; so in config I would type in Warrior and in localization it would show Warrior Description:

I am able to call to the StringVar for live updates, but that does not allow me to use f-string or other concatenation features. And if I use the get() method, I am only receiving the value that is set to classname at window creation. So if I use classname.set("Warrior"), classname.get() will return a string that I can use f-string and I can get it to show Warrior Description. However, get() is a one time call and does not update if I change the data in the config tab.

Below is a barebones implementation to show the general idea of what I have currently. There will be more than one field that will be referenced in the final project and not just the classname field.

**MainProgram.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from ClassConfigTab import ClassConfigTab
from LocalizationTab import LocalizationTab

# Create tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("BG3 Mod Creation Tool")
root.geometry("650x150")

# Create notebook
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
config_tab = ClassConfigTab(nb)
localization_tab = LocalizationTab(config_tab, nb)
nb.add(config_tab, text='Configure class')
nb.add(localization_tab, text='Localization')

# Load window
nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```

**ClassConfigTab.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class ClassConfigTab(ttk.Frame):
    """Content for the required tab for creating a class mod."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.classname = tk.StringVar(name="classname")
        self.classname.set("Warrior")

        self.place_widgets()

    def place_widgets(self):
        entry_classname = ttk.Entry(self, width=50, textvariable=self.classname)

        # Place widgets
        entry_classname.grid(column=0,
                             row=1,
                             padx=10,
                             pady=0,
                             sticky=tk.W)
```

**LocalizationTab.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class LocalizationTab(ttk.Frame):
    """This will contain what is going to be shown on the localization tab."""

    def __init__(self, config_tab, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # This updates automatically but can't use f-string.
        self.label_main_name = ttk.Label(self,
                                         textvariable=config_tab.classname)
        # This loads the StringVar value on window creation, but does not auto update.
        self.label_main_name_two = ttk.Label(self,
                                             text=config_tab.classname.get())

        self.place_widgets()

    def place_widgets(self):
        self.label_main_name.grid(column=0,
                                  row=0,
                                  padx=10,
                                  pady=5,
                                  sticky=tk.W)
        self.label_main_name_two.grid(column=1,
                                      row=0,
                                      padx=10,
                                      pady=5,
                                      sticky=tk.W)
```

I have searched through StackOverflow and found other questions that are similar. They have referenced used trace, bind events, and even just having a button that you press to refresh data.

I have tried both trace and bind, and have had no luck. Perhaps the way I had implemented it was not correct and I apologize, but I do not have the code still in my files to show my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can use `trace()` on tkinter variable:

```py
class LocalizationTab(ttk.Frame):
    """This will contain what is going to be shown on the localization tab."""

    def __init__(self, config_tab, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.config_tab = config_tab  # save for later access

        self.label_main_name = ttk.Label(self)
        # call self.update_label() whenever the variable is updated
        config_tab.classname.trace_add("write", self.update_label)

        self.place_widgets()
        self.update_label()  # update label initially

    def place_widgets(self):
        self.label_main_name.grid(column=0,
                                  row=0,
                                  padx=10,
                                  pady=5,
                                  sticky=tk.W)

    def update_label(self, *args):
        self.label_main_name["text"] = f"{self.config_tab.classname.get()} Description:"
```

Comment: So I was just using it wrong! Thank you! Hours of banging my head against a wall.